# SQLite Update Database Row in Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to update a SQLite Database Row by using this code:

```
public void  updateProfile(String profileName, String col3, String col4, String col5, String col6, String col7, String col8, String col9, String col10, String col11, String col12, String col13, String col14, String col15, String col16, String col17){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET "
            + COL3 + " = '" + col3
            + COL4 + " = '" + col4
            + COL5 + " = '" + col5
            + COL6 + " = '" + col6
            + COL7 + " = '" + col7
            + COL8 + " = '" + col8
            + COL9 + " = '" + col9
            + COL10 + " = '" + col10
            + COL11 + " = '" + col11
            + COL12 + " = '" + col12
            + COL13 + " = '" + col13
            + COL14 + " = '" + col14
            + COL15 + " = '" + col15
            + COL16 + " = '" + col16
            + COL17 + " = '" + col17
            + "' WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + profileName + "'";

    Log.d(TAG, "update Profile: " + profileName);
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

For some reason i get some errors.

Comment: post your error/exception too here.

Comment: Please mention the table schema and the errors that you are getting for better understanding.

Comment: Also take some time and read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399

Comment: Is there a syntax error? It looks like the values need closing "'"

Answer (score 0):

You have two recurring mistakes/errors :-

1. you are omitting a closing single quote around the value that is being set, and
2. you are omitting the , (comma) between the individual set clauses.

You want :-

```
public int  updateProfile(String profileName, String col3, String col4, String col5, String col6, String col7, String col8, String col9, String col10, String col11, String col12, String col13, String col14, String col15, String col16, String col17){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET "
            + COL3 + " = '" + col3 + "',"
            + COL4 + " = '" + col4 + "',"
            + COL5 + " = '" + col5 + "',"
            + COL6 + " = '" + col6 + "',"
            + COL7 + " = '" + col7 + "',"
            + COL8 + " = '" + col8 + "',"
            + COL9 + " = '" + col9 + "',"
            + COL10 + " = '" + col10 + "',"
            + COL11 + " = '" + col11 + "',"
            + COL12 + " = '" + col12 + "',"
            + COL13 + " = '" + col13 + "',"
            + COL14 + " = '" + col14 + "',"
            + COL15 + " = '" + col15 + "',"
            + COL16 + " = '" + col16 + "',"
            + COL17 + " = '" + col17
            + "' WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + profileName + "'";

    Log.d(TAG, "update Profile: " + profileName);
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

- Note the above is untested but in principle is what you want.

## However;

simpler and less prone to errors is to let the SQLiteDatabase **[update](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D))** convenience method do the work of generating the SQL for you. As such I'd suggest using :-

```
public void  updateProfile(String profileName, String col3, String col4, String col5, String col6, String col7, String col8, String col9, String col10, String col11, String col12, String col13, String col14, String col15, String col16, String col17){

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL3,col3);
    cv.put(COL4,col4);
    cv.put(COL5,col5);
    cv.put(COL6,col6);
    cv.put(COL7,col7);
    cv.put(COL8,col8);
    cv.put(COL9,col9);
    cv.put(COL10,col10);
    cv.put(COL11,col11);
    cv.put(COL12,col12);
    cv.put(COL13,col13);
    cv.put(COL14,col14);
    cv.put(COL15,col15);
    cv.put(COL16,col16);
    cv.put(COL17,col17);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.d(TAG, "update Profile: " + profileName);
    return db.update(TABLE_NAME,cv,COL2 + "=?",new String[]{profileName};
 
}
```

- Again this code hasn't been tested or run so it may contain some errors.
- Note the link to the update method above.
- **Note** that `public int updateProfile` has been used, this means that the number of rows that have been updated will be returned, which may be useful.
- the `COL2 + "=?"`, is saying to bind the parameter, that is to replace the **`?`** with the value as per the String[].

  - multiple ?'s can be used for more complex situations, in which case the first ? will be replaced by the first element in the String[], the second ? will be replaced by the 2nd element in the String[] and so on.